# Show and hide table rows in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html-table, hide, show

First, I would like to show all id named `"main` rows and hide all id named `"review"` rows.

Second, when I click on one `"main` row, I would like to show one `"review"` row under this `"main` row.

Third step, And then when I click again on another `"main` row, one `"review"` row will be shown under this `"main` row that I clicked, and the first `"review"` row should be hidden.

In conclusion, I will show only one `"review"` row depending on the `"main`  row that I clicked, and hide all other `"review"` rows to user.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(id,product) in products" ng-controller="ProductMainCtrl as main">
<tr id="main" ng-click="parseProductId(product.product_id)">
  <td>{{product.product_id}}</td>
  <td>{{product.name}}</td>
  <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
  <td>{{order.currency_code}} {{product.unit_price}}</td>
  <td>{{order.currency_code}} {{product.unit_discount}}</td>
  <td>{{order.currency_code}} {{product.price}}</td>
  <td id="arrow"><a>Write A Review</a></td>
</tr>
<tr id="review">
  <td colspan="7">
    <span ng-include="'views/product/rating_main.html'"></span>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Could I get some ideas for that with angular?

Comment: You cannot have multiple ids with the same name; however, you can have multiple classes. It sounds what you're describing is called an Accordion, there's probably an Angular module you can use. I know Angular Bootstrap has one. http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: what you probably want is `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`. Which would allow you to place data in one row and the include in another , all within the same child scope. Don't think of ID's in angular, the data models drive DOM manipulation. You want to use `ng-show` , `ng-hide` etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add an `ng-show` to  your review row and judge which to show by which row your click with `$index` like:

```
<tbody ....>
  ...
  <tr id="review" ng-show'isShow == $index'>
    <td colspan="7">
    <span ng-include="'views/product/rating_main.html'"></span>
  </td>
  </tr>
  ...
</tbody>
```

And add a click function to change `isShow` number:

```
...
<tr id="main" ng-click="parseProductId(product.product_id);changeShow($index)">
...
```

Then define `changeShow` function in controller:

```
$scope.changeShow = function(index){
  $scope.isShow = index;
}
```

Got it.

A sample [here](http://jsbin.com/pibominozi/1/)

Comment: Thanks! If you want to hide the expanded row again on click: Set isShow to -1 if isShow === index